# What situations cause timer interrupts to clash/miss?

Tags: timer, embedded, hardware, interrupt, rtos

I am working on a run-to-completion state-machine RTOS. I am wondering under what conditions can interrupts be missed? Can max CPU utilization conditions (100%) cause interrupts to be missed? Also if two timers having different handlers but same interrupt lines timeout at the same tick, which ISR runs first?

[Appreciate a reply from the perspective of a software/firmware engineer, with limited hardware knowledge.]

Answer (score 4):

The typical way that interrupts are missed is when the first occurrence of an interrupt is not serviced before the second occurrence of the same interrupt source.  When you don't service the first occurrence fast enough then you miss the subsequent occurrence because it can't be distinguished from the first occurrence.  There is no queue to stack up multiple occurrences of an interrupt so you need to service and clear each interrupt before that particular interrupt occurs again.  (Note that different interrupt sources can be pending at the same time and serviced separately because they can be distinguished.  It's two occurrences of the same interrupt source that can cause you to miss one.)

100% CPU utilization doesn't necessarily cause interrupts to be missed but I guess it could contribute.  It's likely to cause other problems as well.

Many microcontrollers include an interrupt prioritization mechanism, which defines which interrupt sources will be asserted over which other interrupts.  This varies from one microcontroller to the next so you'd have to check the data sheet of your particular microcontroller for details.

Update:
So what conditions could cause an interrupt to not be serviced fast enough?
If the interrupts are disabled for too long then an interrupt may not be serviced fast enough.  Or if a higher priority interrupt handler takes too long then a lower priority interrupt may not be serviced fast enough.

To avoid these situations, keep short both the periods where interrupts are disabled and the interrupt handler routines.